# Qualtrics Javascript Convert to ISO Date

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to set up email triggers for surveys on Qualtrics but it's not properly converting to ISOformat. Below is the code.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var date1Container = "${q://QID38/ChoiceTextEntryValue}".split("-");
console.log(date1Container);
var date2Container = "${q://QID40/ChoiceTextEntryValue}".split("-");

var date2 = new Date(date2Container[0], date2Container[1], 
date2Container[2] );
    date2.setHours(12,0);
    var date1 = new Date(date1Container[0], date1Container[1], 
date1Container[2] );
    date1.setHours(12,0);

var REM2 = new Date(date2);
    REM2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 1 );
    REM2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() - 1);
    REM2.setHours(8,30);
var REM1 = new Date(date1);
    REM1.setDate(date1.getDate() -1 );
    REM1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() - 1);
    REM1.setHours(8,30);

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'R1', REM1.toISOString() );
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'R2', REM2.toISOString() );


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com). Load moment.js in the survey header, then it can be used to parse and format the date:

```
var REM1 = moment("${q://QID38/ChoiceTextEntryValue}").toISOString();
```